# I am coming across Switch export error from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am coming across the following error and cannot find a way out of it. Could anyone please help?

> export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath, matchRoutes, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams)

Answer (score 5):

**Instead of using like this**

```
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/users">
          <Users />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
```

**Use like this...**

```
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="users/*" element={<Users />} />
      </Routes>
```

Read this docs: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. It worked nicely for me :)

To import

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route, Redirect,Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Here is the way to implement your routes in App.Jsx file

```
const App = () => {
  const user = true;
  return (<Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `react-router-dom` v6+, then `Switch` is replaced with `Routes`. So you need to simply import `routes` and you can use it here.

Before working in smaller than v6:

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

Now, working in v6 And above

```
import { Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Also You Need to update Route declaration

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

to

```
<Route path='/home' element={<Home/>} />
```

Now, Your error will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear. In order to use `react-router` v6, you'll need to convert all your `<Switch>` elements to `<Routes>`.  See [#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes).

Answer (score 2):

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes
} from "react-router-dom";
```

and use `Routes` insted of `Switch`

its work for this error and got exact solution..

Answer (score 1):

You can import like this,

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes
} from "react-router-dom";
```

and then replace `<Switch>` and `</Switch>` with `<Routes>` and `</Routes>`

Example code is here,

```
<Router>
    <Navbar/>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can import like this:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
```

here is codesandbox example for you :

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-294mt?from-embed=&file=/example.js

Answer (score 0):

latest version of react-router-dom does not need a "switch" and the structure is different. The code will look like this.

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
```

is encapsul
ated in  and "exact" is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also
in Your Index.jsx or main.jsx wrap BrowserRouter over App components

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
    import App from './App'
    import './index.css'
    import {BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

      ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
        <React.StrictMode>
         <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
        </React.StrictMode>
      )
```

Now let's dive into App.jsx

```
    <Routes>
     <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
     <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />}/>
     <Route path="/about" element={<AboutUs/>}/>
    </Routes>
```