# I retrieve two errors when trying to implement nav bar from internet

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I get the following two errors when running the scrips from GeeksforGeeks to create a nav bar in my Reactjs app:

**Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/App.js 23:35-41

export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams)

ERROR in ./src/components/Navbar/NavbarElements.js 3:0-40

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/fa' in 'C:\Users\hella\OneDrive\Documenten\React\test\src\components\Navbar'**

The url where I copied the code from is: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-responsive-navbar-using-reactjs/

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am coming across Switch export error from react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013851/i-am-coming-across-switch-export-error-from-react-router-dom)

Comment: try installing react-icons: `npm i react-icons --save`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed react-router-dom version 6 and Switch does not longer exists, it must be replaced by Routes.

I'll rewrite the tutorial code to match v6 of react-router-dom. This is the file App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages';
import About from './pages/about';
import Events from './pages/events';
import AnnualReport from './pages/annual';
import Teams from './pages/team';
import Blogs from './pages/blogs';
import SignUp from './pages/signup';

function App() {
return (
    <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route path='/events' component={Events} />
        <Route path='/annual' component={AnnualReport} />
        <Route path='/team' component={Teams} />
        <Route path='/blogs' component={Blogs} />
        <Route path='/sign-up' component={SignUp} />
    </Routes>
    </Router>
);
}

export default App;
```

About the error mentioning `react-icons` apparently you don't have it installed, check that